# Reusing layout created on Fragment.onCreateView() to avoid inflation when showing multiple times

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I am using a DialogFragment to display a 'modal' bottom sheet menu (more info here: https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-dialog-fragment/). Since it contains a kind of context menu for the items contained in a RecyclerView, it may be shown multiple times during runtime.

However, always [DialogFragment.show()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment.html#show(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,%20java.lang.String)) is called, [Fragment.onCreateView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) is also called, which leads to layout inflation, which can(?) be considered as a 'heavy' task to be computed in the UI thread, which I want to avoid for performance reasons. So to avoid layout inflation every time the DialogFragment is shown, I created a ViewGroup member object pointing to the View being returned Fragment.onCreateView() in order to be reused, like this:

```
public class BottomMenu extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    private ViewGroup mLayout;
    private TextView mLabel;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (mLayout == null) {
            mLayout = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container, false);
            mLabel = mLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_label);
        }
        return mLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        // The view cannot be reused if it's already attached to the previous parent view
        ((ViewGroup) mLayout.getParent()).removeView(mLayout);
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        mLabel.setText(label)
    }

}
```

But once used for the first time, such view must be detached from the Fragment container view to be reused (see onDismissed() overriden method on posted snippet), which seems like a nasty workaround

**So I post this question to check if anyone knows a better approach to reuse the layout for the same Fragment**

More details here:

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomMenu mBottomMenu;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        [...]
        mBottomMenu = new BottomMenu();
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        mBottomSheet.setLabel(label);
        // The following calls onCreateView() in Fragment, so try to return
        // there the previously inflated layout, if any
        mBottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG?");
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: "which can(?) be considered as a 'heavy' task to be computed in the UI thread" -- not usually, particularly for small layouts like yours. "which I want to avoid for performance reasons" -- why? Do you have evidence that it is causing a problem?

Comment: Well, not actually, but I consider it as a good practice, as could perform better in case of using a heavier layout @CommonsWare

Comment: "I consider it as a good practice" -- why? If you cannot explain how this extra complexity and fragility benefits users, why would it be accepted in a code review? In general, the framework and libraries offers view recycling where such recycling is almost sure to be a benefit (`AdapterView`, `RecyclerView`, `ViewPager`, etc.). Everything else requires some amount of evidence that it would be worth the complexity.

Comment: Just because I do not consider efficient to inflate a layout multiple times when you can use more than once, so if there is a simple way to be more efficient I would use it (even it doesnt introduce significant performance improvements). And I guess the library and framework examples cannot be applicable here, because they are designed to be used widely, for multiple purposes, by lots of developers, where this case is just application specific. I am not looking for premature optimization, just for a proper thing to do this

Comment: "so if there is a simple way to be more efficient I would use it" -- in this case, I do not believe that there is. While there are scenarios where you can reuse fragments and their views, I do not think that it is practical with `DialogFragment` and subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

It is already a nice practice as long as you don't surrender to any possible bugs.. However there are one or two things I want to let you know about resuing dialogFragment.

```
public class BottomMenu extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    private ViewGroup mLayout;
    private TextView mLabel;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (mLayout == null) {
            mLayout = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container, false);
            mLabel = mLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_label);
        } else if(mLayout.getParent()!=null) { // it's not a lot of code. just a few lines……
            ((ViewGroup)mLayout.getParent()).removeView(mLayout);
        }
        return mLayout;
    }
}
```

One thing is about nested fragments. When the dialogFragment hold a viewpager and the viewpager have serveral sub-fragments, you must reset the viewpager's adapter on the reusing-call of `onCreateView`. The reason is that after closing the dialogFragment, the old fragmentManager returned by `getChildFragmentManager()` is no longer valid, and it should be updated.

```
... onCreateView(...)

        if (mLayout == null) {
            ...
        } else { 
            ...
            viewpager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragments));
        }
```

If this step is omitted, you may observe strange behaviours when reusing the dialogFragment, such as recyclerviews in the sub-fragments stop updating in response to `NotifyDatasetChanged`, but if you scroll it, it will update.

Another thing is that I tend to use WeakRefernce to hold the dialogFragment to be reused. I even have an array of them.

In java applications, if you don't use similar mechanism, you can see rapid surge in memory usage when the user open and close the same dialog again and again. So at least it's not a bad practice to reuse dialogs when it's necessary.